# Storing and retrieving two-dimensional and three-dimensional data

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, data-storage

I work on computational geometry.
A huge number of two-dimensional and three-dimensional data are found in my project. Coordinates of polygon and polyhedrons vertices consisted of two-dimensional and three-dimensional data, respectively. Indeed, polyhedrons face data are also founded. Storing and retrieving them is nessecesery in some part of my code.

I want to know is there any efficient storing algorithm for my data which:

1. Require the least time and volume
2. Shapes can be easily retrieved

Please explain it in the simplest because I am new to this kind of algorithm.

I will appreciate any comments that give me a little help and forgive me for writing shortcomings.

Comment: Have you looked into any of the existing computational geometry engines such as CGAL or OpenCASCADE or VTK?

Comment: What sort of queries are you actually looking to do on the geometric entities? Can you give an example of a use case for this geometric data? And when you talk about storage, are you referring to on disk or in a data structure at runtime of some software?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thanks for your comment. No, I didn't. But plus to algorithm, finding its philosophy is also important to me.

Comment: @spektr A large category of actions such as calculating area, volume, convex hall, sorting,...
Both types, either the volume on disk or data structure.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/36607/4274, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/134024/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @D.W. I really do not know the meaning of "what context?". Your next question is clear but I will improve it.